# How we can use swipe in react navigation V3 with bottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-navigation

I'm using react navigation V3 and i want to use swipe in my bottomTabNavigator.
i can't do it because createBottomTabNavigator don't support it any yet and createBottomNavigator is actually deprecated.
It is very annoying because in react navigation V2 we can do iteasily.
Just createMaterialTopTabNavigator support swipe but i want a bottom navigator and not a top one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig) for `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` you can see that in the `TabNavigatorConfig` there is the ability to set the position of the tab bar using `tabBarPosition`

> Position of the tab bar, can be `'top'` or `'bottom'`, default is `top`

So if you use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` instead of `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` and set `tabBarPosition: 'bottom'` in your config you should get a `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` but at the bottom.

Here is what it should look like in code

```
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  }
}

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom' // <- add this line to your config
}

const MainNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(screens,config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Here is a snack showing it working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/materialtopnavigator-at-the-bottom

Comment: Thank you for your help